# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zza

Tags: android, quickblox

**Error** :

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method
>   (Landroid/content/Context;)V in class
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/iid/zzd; or its super classes (declaration of
>   'com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd' appears in
>   /data/app/com.app-1/base.apk:classes33.dex)
>                                                          at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                          at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getInstance(Unknown Source)
>                                                          at com.quickblox.messages.services.a.c.(Unknown Source)

Gradle

```
qbSdkVersion = '3.3.1'

versionName = '3.3.0'

testRunnerVersion = "0.4.1"


// Dependency versions
playServicesVersion = '10.2.1'
supportV4Version = '23.1.1'
appcompatV7Version = '23.1.1'
recyclerviewV7Version = '23.2.1'
supportAnnotationsVersion = '23.1.1'
designVersion = '23.1.1'

uilVersion = '1.9.0'
glideVersion = '3.6.1'
pullToRefreshVersion = '3.2.3'
stickyListHeaders = '2.7.0'
robotoTextViewVersion = '2.4.3'
stickersVersion = '0.7.3'
crashlyticsVersion = '2.2.2'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar issue when I used in my project android-support libs or play-services libs with different versions, check it in your project (you can see it in Android Studio in part 'External Libraries'). In QuickBlox Android SDK (v3.3.1) used play-services version 10.2.1 and support libs version 23.1.1. If you use firebase in your project, it version must be same with play-services version. Additionally check versions this libs in others modules in your project. Also check, maybe other libs from your dependencies use support libs or play-services libs with different versions with your project.

Comment: compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2' is it problem ?

Comment: maybe, just connect same version of play-services, like     compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.2"     or vice versa compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'

Comment: as I wrote before, you can check all versions of used libs in Android Studio in section 'External Libraries'